# How to implement a TCP/IP heartbeat on 2500+ sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets

I currently have an asynchronous TCP/IP socket C# WinForms application that is the "Server" application. The application holds persistent sockets to the clients. I would like to implement a heartbeat packet to detect Half-Open connections.

Initially I thought about just creating a loop and sending the heartbeat to my entire collection of sockets every xx number of seconds. However, I think this would be bad for performance.

I think I should somehow stagger the heartbeat and send to a few hundred sockets at once. Does anyone have any experience/techniques/implementations for effectively accomplishing this?

Comment: have you tried a for loop?  </sarcasm>

Comment: Yep. But sending to all 2500+ connections (which will grow in the future) all at once seems like a bad idea. Would you recommend sending all at once?

Comment: Hmm, I understand your concern, really. I would suggest 'segmenting' your socket collection into 'blocks' (if it's a vector or anything of the sort). Create an instance variable 'BlockCounter', which gets increased each time the Keep-Alive timer hits Zero. Then do a for-loop ranging from BlockCounter*100 to (BlockCounter+1)*100.

Comment: I'm kidding. You would probably be best sending an empty packet every 60 seconds or 120 seconds or so (which the client will ACK).  If a client misses 2 in a row, drop them. Since you're using asynchronous IO, there wouldn't really be any benefit to staggering them, so you might as well just do them all at once.  You could maybe even make a heartbeat thread to handle it, or even better, a network thread whose sole purpose was to handle the network, which handled the heartbeat as well as all other transfers. This thread could interface to the rest of the program with wait queues of some sort.

Comment: @Wug My main concern is server load. If I did all at once, the rest of the server operations take a hit. If i send to 10000 at once, it would be even worse. Since I am using TCP/IP, if I cant reach the client on the first heartbeat, they are gone.

Comment: @ATaylor I like that idea. Thanks.

Comment: What sort of application are we dealing with?  A database of some sort? A game client? Status checker? (botnet?)

Comment: The application holds persistent TCP/IP connections to devices. The application communicates back to the devices and logs data into a database. The database is then used for a website. The website also communicates with the application via WCF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do this (for an order-of-magnitude more sockets) simply by tracking how long ago I last spoke to (or heard from) a particular socket.on an interval, I ping those over a given age. Assuming sockets connect / disconnect / communicate uniformly, this gives me a fairly uniform distribution. Besides, you can always cap the ping to a finite number of sockets per iteration: because you're tracking the last-talked info, the ones you don't get to will still be eligible next time.

Comment: This is a good idea. My sockets are communicating uniformly and are already contained within an object. I will just add an "age" variable. Thanks :)

Comment: Marc I have a similar console application which is  the server however , I dont care if the socket is connected because I keep track of messages with [`isMessageRead()`](http://i.imgur.com/owLiF2q.png) in the server. so even if the client is disconnected , the next time it reconnects he asks : _"do I have any unread messages?"_ and for each message the client reads - it removes from the server dictionary. but the problem is on the other direction. I don't know if the *server* is alive or not. I use `isMessageRead` in order to check but it works only if I run it locally.(127.0.0.1) however -

Comment: - If I run `IsSocketconnected` from local to my world IP +port  -  the client still thinks the server is ON !. does your solution will help me in my situation also ? if not . can you please just redirect me to a solution (just the general idea of solving it)

Comment: @Royi nope; see "half open sockets" and "half closed sockets". Sometimes it is undetectable, especially when crossing subnets means that TCP keep-alive isn't available. Your best option: agree that client and server will always talk at least (some frequency), else: nix the socket